# Working with YAML for Scala

Tags: scala, yaml

I found one library for this https://github.com/daltontf/scala-yaml, but it seems like not many developers use it and it's pretty outdated. It also might be this http://www.lag.net/configgy/ if the link wasn't dead.

I wonder, what is the most popular or de-facto library for working with YAML in Scala?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) is a high-quality, actively maintained YAML parser/renderer for Java.  You can of course use it from Scala.

If you're already working with [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/), you might be interested in [circe-yaml](https://github.com/circe/circe-yaml) which uses [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) to parse a YAML file and then converts the result to a circe AST.

I would love to see a library that could parse either JSON or YAML (or whatever -- pluggable) to a common AST and then construct Scala objects using typeclasses.  Several JSON libraries work like that (and of course can also render JSON for objects using the same typeclasses), but I don't know of such a facility for YAML.

---

PS: There also appear to be a number of seemingly abandoned wrappers for SnakeYAML, namely [HelicalYAML](https://github.com/liuhongchao/helicalyaml) and [yaml4s](https://github.com/GranData/yaml4s)

Comment: The HelicalYAML is not maintained at the moment (according to the project website; latest commit was in 2010)

Comment: For me the main disadvantage of using SnakeYAML is that you can only serialize mutable class with java collection if you want auto-parsing using reflection. That makes me to write 2 classes. Immutable one to use in code and beany-one that has @BeanProperties and uses java collections with build method on it to construct immutable companion. Did I miss something? Maybe there are some macros-based meta programming solutions to free me from double-coding?

Comment: [circe-yaml](https://github.com/circe/circe-yaml) was mentioned below by @SemanticBeeng. It translates SnakeYAML's AST into circe's AST and enables parsing YAML 1.1 documents into circe's Json AST.

Answer (score 27):

Here's an example of using the [Jackson YAML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) databinding.

First, here's our sample document:

```
name: test
parameters:
  "VERSION": 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

things:
  - colour: green 
    priority: 128
  - colour: red
    priority: 64
```

Add these dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.1.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.1.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.1.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-yaml" % "2.1.1"
)
```

Here's our outermost class (Preconditions is a Guava-like check and raises an exception if said field is not in the YAML):

```
import java.util.{List => JList, Map => JMap}
import collection.JavaConversions._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

class Sample(@JsonProperty("name") _name: String,
             @JsonProperty("parameters") _parameters: JMap[String, String],
             @JsonProperty("things") _things: JList[Thing]) {
  val name = Preconditions.checkNotNull(_name, "name cannot be null")
  val parameters: Map[String, String] = Preconditions.checkNotNull(_parameters, "parameters cannot be null").toMap
  val things: List[Thing] = Preconditions.checkNotNull(_things, "things cannot be null").toList
}
```

And here's the inner object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

class Thing(@JsonProperty("colour") _colour: String,
            @JsonProperty("priority") _priority: Int {
  val colour = Preconditions.checkNotNull(_colour, "colour cannot be null")
  val priority = Preconditions.checkNotNull(_priority, "priority cannot be null")
}
```

Finally, here's how to instantiate it:

```
 val reader = new FileReader("sample.yaml")
 val mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
 val config: Sample = mapper.readValue(reader, classOf[Sample])
```

Comment: I've been using 'jackson-dataformat-yaml' for maintaining application config many months now. Found it better than SnakeYaml.

Comment: Thank you for the example! I would change Guava preconditions to:
`require(_colour != null, "colour cannot be null"); val colour = _colour`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @r90t - I wrote this a while ago and it was my first foray into Scala.

Answer (score 25):

A little late to the party but I think this method works in the most seamless way. This method has:

1. Automatic conversion to scala collection types
2. Use case classes
3. No need for boilerplate code like BeanProperty/JsonProperty
4. Uses [Jackson-YAML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) & [Jackson-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala)

Code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

case class Prop(url: List[String])

// uses Jackson YAML to parsing, relies on SnakeYAML for low level handling
val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())

// provides all of the Scala goodiness
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val prop: Prop = mapper.readValue("url: [abc, def]", classOf[Prop])

// prints List(abc, def)
println(prop.url)
```

Comment: 3 years in *not* late for *this* topic - given it is still not a completely solved one.  I am using the given libraries above successfully but continue to run into specific gotchas.

Answer (score 11):

And now we have `circe-yaml` https://github.com/circe/circe-yaml

> *SnakeYAML provides a Java API for parsing YAML and marshalling its structures into JVM classes. However, you might find circe's way of marshalling into a Scala ADT preferable -- using compile-time specification or derivation rather than runtime reflection. This enables you to parse YAML into Json, and use your existing (or circe's generic) Decoders to perform the ADT marshalling. You can also use circe's Encoder to obtain a Json, and print that to YAML using this library.*

Answer (score 6):

I came across [moultingyaml](https://github.com/jcazevedo/moultingyaml) today.

> MoultingYAML is a Scala wrapper for SnakeYAML based on spray-json.

It looks quite familiar to me, having worked years with `spray-json`. I think it might fit @sihil's need of a "compelling" and "mature" Scala YAML library.

Comment: Moultingyaml seems to support single case clases which is a *very* limited scope. I want support for nested maps and lists.

Comment: Moultingyaml takes the same abstraction level as spray.json, and for spray.json one can do about 20-line pattern match to handle what I think you want.

Comment: @akauppi.. Could you please suggest your inputs on this question as well.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188174/facing-issue-while-reading-a-yaml-file-using-moultingyaml

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else that runs across this answer and is looking for help and examples, I found a [basic example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-yaml-parser-parsing-examples-snakeyaml-objects) that uses snakeYAML Hope it helps. Here's the code:

```
package yaml

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.reflect.BeanProperty

object YamlBeanTest1 {

  val text = """
  accountName: Ymail Account
  username: USERNAME
  password: PASSWORD
  mailbox: INBOX
  imapServerUrl: imap.mail.yahoo.com
  protocol: imaps
  minutesBetweenChecks: 1
  usersOfInterest: [barney, betty, wilma]
  """

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(classOf[EmailAccount]))
    val e = yaml.load(text).asInstanceOf[EmailAccount]
    println(e)
  }

}

/**
 * With the Snakeyaml Constructor approach shown in the main method,
 * this class must have a no-args constructor.
 */
class EmailAccount {
  @BeanProperty var accountName: String = null
  @BeanProperty var username: String = null
  @BeanProperty var password: String = null
  @BeanProperty var mailbox: String = null
  @BeanProperty var imapServerUrl: String = null
  @BeanProperty var minutesBetweenChecks: Int = 0
  @BeanProperty var protocol: String = null
  @BeanProperty var usersOfInterest = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()

  override def toString: String = {
    return format("acct (%s), user (%s), url (%s)", accountName, username, imapServerUrl)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So I don't have enough reputation to comment (41 atm) but I thought my experience was worth mentioning.

After reading this thread, I decided to try to use the Jackson YAML parser because I didn't want zero-argument constructors and it was much more readable. What I didn't realize was that **there is no support for inheritance (merging), and there is limited support for anchor reference** (isn't that the whole point of YAML??).

Merge is explained [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/issues/20).

Anchor reference is explained [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/issues/3). While it appears that complex anchor reference is supported, I could not get it to work in a simple case.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience JSON libraries for Scala are more mature and easier to use (none of the YAML approaches are enormously compelling or as mature as JSON equivalents when it comes to dealing with case classes or writing custom serialisers and deserialisers).

As such I prefer to converting from YAML to JSON and then use a JSON library. this might sound slightly crazy but it works really well provided that:

- You are only working with YAML that is a subset of JSON (a great deal of use cases in my experience)
- The path is not performance critical (as there is overhead in taking this approach)

The approach I use for converting from YAML to JSON leverages Jackson:

```
val tree = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory()).readTree(yamlTemplate)

val json = new ObjectMapper()
        .writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter().withoutSpacesInObjectEntries())
        .writeValueAsString(tree)
```