# YAML to Scala code generation

Tags: scala, yaml, scala-2.10

I want to generate Scala code from YAML , I tried to make case class manually, but does not look good . Is there any API / open source available to generate Scala code from YAML.

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441400/working-with-yaml-for-scala)

Comment: It's pretty meaningless to convert YAML to Scala *source*. Do you mean you want to read and parse YAML in a Scala application?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul , I want to make scala classes (*.scala file) by reading YAML.

Comment: But YAML is a markup language, not a programming language. So it makes no sense - there isn't a Scala class that corresponds to a YAML file. If you mean you want to create objects corresponding to the YAML, that would make sense. And @sacha-cs's link is what you need there