# Read Dynamic Yaml File through Scala Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Need help, I am having a YAML file. Need to read this yml file and write scala spark code accordingly. Below is my yml file.

after reading profile. First lets say 'SubscriberProfilePanel' is my table name then  'highUtilizationScoreData' is my column name then count is the condition for which I have written a function to apply on. So basically I have to read this dynamic Yaml file as the number of fields like table,field can be more or less. The thing that is fixed are 'SubscriberProfilePanel' name,copy or count the conditions thats all. So can anyone help me how to read the dynamic yml file through java or scala in spark?

```
profile: 
    SubscriberProfilePanel: 
        activationDate: 
            copy: 
                table: SubscriebrAudirLog
                field: activationDateCust
        highUtilizationScoreData: 
            count: 
                table: FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource
                field: subscriber_key
                filters:
                    operator: AND
                    1: 
                        dateCompare: 
                            date1: 
                                table: FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource
                                field: effective_date_ge
                            operator: <
                            date2: 
                                table: FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource
                                field: currentBillCycleStartDate
                    2: 
                        dateCompare: 
                            date1: 
                                table: FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource
                                field: effective_date_ge
                            operator: <
                            date2: 
                                table: FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource
                                field: threeBillCyclesStartDate
                                origin: destination
                        numCompare: 
                            num1: 
                                table: FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource
                                field: threshold
                            operator: >=
                            num2: 
                                table: FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource
                                field: 80
    AccountProfilePanel: 
    HomeProfilePanel: 
    PrepaidProfilePanel:
```

I tried but not getting a good yml read code that can able to read every values so that I can pass it into variable in my scala code.

I have written the below code , I able to read and parse the YML file, but how I will able to get all the values inside each variable so that I can call my methods accordingly. Like to check if 'copy' is there or not if there then will check its filed value and table name.

the code is like below

```scala
var yamlData = 
   spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles( "/Users/ayushgup/Desktop/SUN_DV/data_validation.yml")
     .map(x => x._2)
     .collect()(0)

val yaml = new Yaml()
var config = 
      yaml.load(yamlData)
        .asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]
var item = config.values().contains("activationDate") //.get("SubscriberProfilePanel")
println(item)
print (config)
```

the output I got is

```
{profile={SubscriberProfilePanel={activationDate={copy={table=SubscriebrAudirLog, field=activationDateCust}}, highUtilizationScoreData={count={table=FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource, field=subscriber_key, filters={operator=AND, 1={dateCompare={date1={table=FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource, field=effective_date_ge}, operator=greater, date2={table=FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource, field=currentBillCycleStartDate}}}, 2={dateCompare={date1={table=FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource, field=effective_date_ge}, operator=greater, date2={table=FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource, field=threeBillCyclesStartDate, origin=destination}}, numCompare={num1={table=FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource, field=threshold}, operator=less_equal, num2={table=FactADHPostpaidSubscriptionDataThresholdLimitSource, field=80}}}}}}}, AccountProfilePanel=null, HomeProfilePanel=null
```

Please do help me here

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441400/working-with-yaml-for-scala/19461148

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please help me out here